# Netcat result as a perl script argument

Tags: perl, shell, netcat

I'm traying to get the output of netcat as a perl script argument in linux :) , here is my perl code: `while(1){ if(@ARGV>1){some traitement ....}`
in the terminal I tested this: `netcat -l -u -p 1111 | perl myscript.pl`
and this is not working, I'm receiving data I can check it on wireshark.
but this data need to be redirected to myscript.pl as parameter. if it is possible to do it with .sh file it will be ok.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the output to `perl`'s STDIN. You can simply do the following to read it:

```
while (<>) {
   ...
}
```

If you really need the output as a parameter, use the following (but keep in mind there are limits on the size of parameters):

```
perl myscript.pl "$( netcat ... )"
```

Comment: thank you, effectively I did passing the output to the perl's STDIN, I was thinking about using the 'cat' command in the same time as natcat. i tested your solutions but it seams not working for same reason. for more comprehension this is all my perl script: while(1){ if(@ARGV>1){ print $ARGV[0];}}. I think that because netcat is always listening.

Comment: Again, you need to change your Perl script, or change how you pass the data to it. Note that `perl myscript.pl "$( netcat ... )"` will only launch `perl` after `netcat` exits, so I repeat my recommendation: Change your script to `while (<>) { ... }`.

Comment: I tested your two methods M. ikegami. sorry but not working :).

Comment: Are you sure ? 10 bytes over UDP (without EOF)can be piped to perl script ?

Comment: Of course 10 bytes can be piped to `perl`. But did you? Your `netcat` might be buffering. Mine buffers until it sees a newline (or its buffer gets full).

Answer (score 0):

use xargs like this (older/different netcat program called nc)

```
nc -l 1111 | xargs perl -e '$!=1;print @ARGV'
```

At the other end of the socket send an EOF.  Once this happens all the parameters are passed to the script

Comment: thank you, this is not working even for a simple print: netcat -l -u -p 1111 | xargs perl -e '$!=1;print @ARGV'.

Comment: example (now corrected) works as shown.  Sorry don't have "netcat" installed to test

Comment: thank you M.Vorsprung, I'm receiving UDP hex data without EOF lol.

Comment: Maybe the lack of EOF is the problem, it won't ever make a list, it's always a stream